# Where do those characters come?

Tags: character-encoding, char

I heard `UTF-8` and `UTF-16`. But where do the following characters come?

```
1　⊙●○①⊕◎Θ⊙¤㊣★☆♀◆◇◣◢◥▲▼△▽⊿◤ ◥
2　▆ ▇ █ █ ■ ▓ 回 □ 〓≡ ╝╚╔ ╗╬ ═ ╓ ╩ ┠ ┨┯ ┷┏ .
3　┓┗ ┛┳⊥﹃﹄┌ ┐└ ┘∟「」↑↓→←↘↙♀♂┇┅ ﹉﹊﹍﹎╭ .
4　╮╰ ╯ *^_^* ^*^ ^-^ ^_^ ^︵^ ∵∴‖︱ ︳︴﹏﹋﹌︵︶︹︺ .
5　【】〖〗＠﹕﹗/ " _  `,·。≈{}~ ～() _ -『』√ $ @ * & # ※ .
6　卐 々∞Ψ ∪∩∈∏ の ℡ ぁ §∮〝〞ミ灬ξ№∑⌒ξζω＊
7 ¡ Þ ↘ ㊣ ◎ ○ ● ⊕ ⊙ ○△ ▲ ☆ ★ ◇ ◆ ■ ▄ █ ▌ ♀ ♥ ⊙ ◎ ↔ ◊ の ★☆⊕◎Θ\﹏﹋﹌【】〖〗※-『』√∴卐 ≈ ∵∴§∮•.•♠♣♂ ◊ ♠ ♣ の ☆→ ぃ ￡ ..
```

Comment: That’s a mix of characters. They came here because you sent them. They are all representable in UTF-8 as well as in the UTF-16. There is no real question here.

Comment: You can browse and search for Unicode characters and their encodings [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/index.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the characters are from the IBM Extended Ascii character set.

http://ascii-table.com/ascii-extended-pc-table.php

Comment: “Extended Ascii” is a misnomer, and this particular “Extended Ascii” contains only a small part of the characters in the question.